# Remove chapter name from header just from first page of TOCs - part 2

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

This question is building off the [solution posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356249/remove-chapter-name-from-header-just-from-first-page-of-tocs).

For example, **ONLY** on the first pages of the contents pages (like contents, List of Figures, etc.), I wanted to remove the chapter name from the header so that the first page of the TOC, LOFs etc. will look like this:

[image]

but the following pages related to the TOC, LOFs etc. should have the chapter name in the header like this:

[image]

Here is the original solution code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{fancy}}{}{}


\newif\ifchapterwidthstar
\newcommand\printchapternumber{\ifchapterwidthstar\else\thechapter\fi}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstarfalse\@afterheading}{}{}
\patchcmd\@schapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstartrue\@afterheading}{}{}
\makeatother
\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven
\newcommand*{\headimages}[3][]{%
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\headimages{example-image-b}{example-image-a}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\printchapternumber};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}
\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument


\appendix
\chapter{Answer 1}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example minimal and remove all unnecessary code (e.g. are the tikzpictures or the footlines really important?).

Comment: @TeXnician, I removed the code for the footer but left the header code as I think that it is needed for part of the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: well if you can accept a manual solution you can do `\newpage\markright{}\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to believe this is what is intended, but it seems to be what you ask.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{semifancy}\pagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\newif\ifchapterwidthstar
\newcommand\printchapternumber{\ifchapterwidthstar\else\thechapter\fi}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstarfalse\@afterheading}{}{}
\patchcmd\@schapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstartrue\@afterheading}{}{}
\makeatother
\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven
\newcommand*{\headimages}[3][]{%
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\headimages{example-image-b}{example-image-a}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\printchapternumber};
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancypagestyle{semifancy}{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}%
  \fancyhead[E]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
      \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
      \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
      \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \fancyhead[O]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
      \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
      \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
      \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\printchapternumber};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
      \fi
      \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}
\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\appendix
\chapter{Answer 1}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{References}

\end{document}
```

[image: likely unwanted, but who knows?]

Why is `TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED` hard-coded in the definitions? And why does the content overlay the logo?

Aside from that, I find the layout extremely confusing as I can't tell where one chapter ends and the next begins at all easily. It looks like more and more of just the same.